# Creating knex migration

Tags: knex.js

I find out there is two way we can write knex migration in the migration file.

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema
      .createTableIfNotExists('foo', function (table) {
        table.increments('id').unique();
        table.string('foo1');
        table.string('foo2');
      })
     .createTableIfNotExists('bar', function (table) {
        table.increments('bar1');
        table.string('bar2').index();
      });
```

Or

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return Promise.all([
      knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('foo', function (table) {
        table.increments('id').unique();
        table.string('foo1');
        table.string('foo2');
      }),
      knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('bar', function (table) {
        table.increments('bar1');
        table.string('bar2').index();
      })
    ]);
}
```

Which one is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered by [Ricardo Graca](https://github.com/ricardograca) at [Knex's github issue page](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1333)

> *In that case it doesn't make a difference.*
>
> *You would only use the Promise based one if you require some change in*
>   *a table before doing another change in another table. For example, if*
>   *you needed to reference a certain table from another table and none of*
>   *those tables exist yet, you would create the first table (the one that*
>   *doesn't depend on anything) in a promise and then when that promise*
>   *resolved you would create the second table. That way you ensure that*
>   *dependencies are met.*

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way to add knex script, as Promises are the preferred way of dealing with queries in knex, as they allow you to return values from a fulfillment handler.

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
return Promise.all([
  knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('foo', function (table) {
    table.increments('id').unique();
    table.string('foo1');
    table.string('foo2');
  }),
  knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('bar', function (table) {
    table.increments('bar1');
    table.string('bar2').index();
  })
]);
}
```